# How do we use $Δh=v(Δp)$ in pumps assuming $ΔT=0$ while the temperature can increase for the fluid such as in rankine cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

In incompressible fluids, for liquids &  Constant-temperature processes, as in pumps $(ΔT=0)$ then $Δh=v(Δp)$ . But for a pump in Rankine cycle it will increase the temperature.So, how will  we use $ Δ h=Δp(v)$ and assume the $ΔT=0$?

Comment: How much does it increase in the pump, considering it would have to involve viscous heating with a low viscosity fluid flowing?

Comment: What type of pump?  For centrifugal pumps with a given impeller diameter, a constant flow rate, and turning at a constant rpm, you get a constant "head".  This means that the pressure differential across the pump is a function of fluid density for the stated conditions.